# Onclick event firing twice while using iscroll

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, phonegap-plugins, iscroll4

I am using nested iscroll4 but the onclick event on

firing two times.
first added a div just for swipe using iscroll and its li is below:-

```
     <li>     
           <div class="pullContainer">
            <div class="wraps" id="w1">
              <div class="scrolls" id="sc1">
                <div id="pullDown1" class="pullDowns">
                 <span class="pullDownIcon"></span>
                   <span class="pullDownLabel1">Pull down to refresh...</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="scrollContainer" id="nearBy"></div>
                   <!-- Template  container -->
                 <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                  {{if (data.length > 0)}}
                 <ul class = "forSmooth" id="nearbyList">
                  {{each data}}
                  <li class = "smooth" data-businessId = "${$value.id}" data-distance = "${$value.distance}" data-prev-page ="homePage" onclick = "alert('hi');">
```

Here the alert is firing two times...So how can i prevent this by firing second time.

Comment: where is jquery code?

Comment: I am retriving the values using API.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<li class = "smooth" data-businessId = "${$value.id}" data-distance = "${$value.distance}" data-prev-page ="homePage" onclick = "AlertFunction()";">

function AlertFunction(e){
    alert("Hi");
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

*Note : Totally untested code*

Comment: try e.preventDefault();

Comment: can you put a fiddle ? or JSBin ?

Comment: Its a very long code and i am doing it using api.So I can't.